SCP Changes between 22.04 and 24.04
Just upgraded from 22.04 to 24.04.  I use a very simple script to backup my server to a Windows machine.  The command I used was:
scp -r /home/luser/ 'wuser@192.168.0.8:"G:/Network Backup/Proxmox/Speedtest/"'

It worked fine for my purposes.  Now under 24.04 it no longer works.  I get the following errors:
scp: stat remote: No such file or directory
scp: failed to upload directory /home/luser to "G:/Network Backup/Proxmox/Speedtest/"

Any help and/or advise would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Is the behavior different if you add the -O option to force legacy scp protocol in place of the new default sftp?

i don t know if it the same probleme, but i can t use scp on my 24.04.
scp user@ip:/myfile ./myfile

it work before and on others computeurs with V22.04
now on this one i have
bash: line 1: /usr/lib/sftp-server: No such file or directory
scp: Connection closed


same probleme for me
thank 's it work with -O
scp -O user@ip:/MyFile ./MyFile

